# How does Image Cache works in Browser

Tags: image, caching, seo

How can I make my Image cached by browser and expire after particular period of time

Answer (score 1):

There are several HTTP headers that you can use to effect changes to the content caching policies.

This one:

```
Cache-control: no-cache
```

instructs the browser not to cache the content at all.

This one:

```
Expires: Tue, 20 Mar 2024 02:00:00 GMT
```

instructs the browser to expire its cached copy by the given time.

This one:

```
ETag: ab10be20
```

instructs the browser to consider `ab10be20` as a hash of the contents and only if the value changes upon subsequent requests should it need to download the new contents.

Note that all of these are effectively advisory only and there's no possible way to enforce the purging of caches remotely.